# Does .get() in C++ return null for file reading?

Tags: c++

When reading in a source file and storing individual chars into a buffer, does the `.get()` method return `NULL` when it reaches the end of the file in C++ and sees that there are no more chars to be read from? The `.get()` method in this case is from the `iostream` library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

...
char c = source_file.get();

while(bufferList.size() < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
{
   if (c != NULL)
   {
      ... // Add chars to buffer.
   }
   else // c is Null
   {
      bufferList.push_back('$');
   }
   // Get the next char from the file
   c = source_file.get();
}
```

Where I am using `$` to symbolize the EOF marker.

Instead of saying `if (c != NULL)` could I just say `if(c)`? Does that mean the same thing and if `c` is `NULL`, `if(c)` would evaluate to false?

Comment: `c` is not a pointer. It will default to an `int` in this case

Comment: How would I go about testing whether the source_file has gotten to the very end then?

Comment: You would call `fstat`, then look at the `st_size ` value, then read that many bytes.

Comment: @self: No, it doesn't *default* to `int`. It returns `int` because it's declared to return `int`. And why would calling `fstat` and looking at `st_size` be better than checking the value returned by `get`? `fstat` is defined by POSIX, not by C++, so it might not be available, and the size of the file can change between the `fstat` call and your input operation.

Comment: @KeithThompson, that's a pretty rich statement "it can change..blah blah" Yes of course it can, but fstat is actually the preferred way to do it. You can check the return value of `fread` to see if it _did_ actually change. (fread() != st.st_size) Furthermore, based on this code, `c` would be an int. BECAUSE HE didn't declare a type for it.

Comment: @user3869795 Did you consider to read the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) before asking here?

Comment: @self: The `get` function in question is a member function of `std::basic_istream`, documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). It is explicitly declared as an `int` function by the implementation. C++ does not have an "implicit `int`"` rule; if a function is not visibly declared with an explicit return type, you can't call it (constructors and destructors are special cases, not applicable here). As for `fstat` being the "preferred way to do it", it's not. (BTW, C hasn't had an "implicit `int`" rule since the 1999 standard, though many compilers still support it.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Maybe since you're at a higher level of abstraction here in the C++ land, but eventually you're going to perform a _system_ call to the kernel to get the size of the file. (fstat is one of them)

Comment: @self: No, if you're reading input from a file, you don't necessarily need to know its size. Just read until you can't read any more. Checking the size of a file does not reliably tell you how much you can read from it. On Windows, for example, the equivalent of `fstat` would presumably tell you the size in bytes of the file on disk; when you read from it as text, each 2-byte end-of-line marker is translated to a single `'\n'` character, so the sizes don't match. And the size can change, other things can go wrong, and not all readable files *have* a size (what's the size of keyboard input)?

Comment: @KeithThompson, well I accept defeat :) Good points about the read until EOF thing. That is also the major difference between reading from a pipe and reading from a file

Comment: @self: But, but ... this is the Internet! That never happens! 8-)} (Just one more point: there needn't be any difference between reading from a file vs. reading from a pipe; the same code can do both perfectly well. See most UNIX utilities, for example.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, but reading from a pipe will block if there is no data, reading from a file will return EOF when there is nothing left to read, no? My OS class just had this question, actually.

Comment: @self: Yes --- and? You can write system-specific code to deal with pipes blocking (once you've decided just *how* you want to respond other than just waiting for more input), but there's usually no need for that. And such cases are far beyond what the OP is asking about. The `grep` command, for example, doesn't know or care where its input is coming from; it just reads it and processes it as a stream of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

This is specified in the documentation for the `get` function. For example, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get says:

> `int_type get();`
>
> Reads one character and returns it if available. Otherwise, returns `Traits::eof()` and sets `failbit` and `eofbit`.

You can check `failbit` and/or `eofbit` to determine *why* no input was available, but you should do so, if at all, only after checking the value returned by `get()`.

(I presume that `Traits::eof()` is very likely to be the same value as `EOF`, but I'm not certain of that.)

It doesn't return `NULL`, because `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant, not an `int` value. Well, actually `NULL` is defined as `0`, so `(c != NULL)` could compile, but it wouldn't do what you want; it's equivalent to `(c != '\0')`, which tests whether you just read a null character. (For text input, you'll probably never see a null character; for binary input, a null byte doesn't imply end-of-file.)

And you need to assign the result of `get()` to an `int` object, not a `char` object.

As for the best way to handle this, opinions differ. Personally I'd likely write something like:

```
int c;
while ((c = source_file.get()) != EOF) {
    // ...
}
```

(That's influenced by my C background.)

Checking the stream state is another option (I won't try to demonstrate that).

Comment: In my if statement would I instead then say `if(c != Traits::eof())` and then proceed with the body of the statement?

Comment: @user3869795: I believe so. I'm not familiar enough with C++ input to be certain. And you could reorganize your loop so there's only one call to `get()`.

Comment: I tried checking if `c != Traits::eof()` and got an error saying `Traits has not been declared`. If `.get()` returns a char, why is the type an `int` then? I am looking at the documentation for it and don't understand how it can be an int but it returns a char.

Comment: @user3869795 Again, read the reference documentation 1st please!

Comment: @user3869795: It returns an `int` so that it can return either a `char` value *or* a distinct value that indicates there's no more input.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did read the reference documentation first. The thing is I didn't understand it so I'm seeking clarification, so telling me to read what I already have read and don't understand doesn't help me.

Comment: @KeithThompson That does help clarify a bit. I changes `c` to be an `int` instead of a `char` and it compiled without error, but I'm still having trouble determining how to check for the `eof()`. The documentation mentiones the `eofbit` and `failbit` but I don't know how to access those.

Comment: @user3869795 `eof()` is a stream state, and not necessarily a special character read from the file. That simple. You can access the stream states through [`rdstate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdstate)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: So what's the *idiomatic* C++ way to do this? Check the value returned by `.get()`, or check the `.eof()` stream state? In C, the idiom is `int c; while ((c = getchar() != EOF) { /* ... */ }`. The same kind of thing should work in C++, but what's considered best practice?

Comment: @Keith I'd prefer checking the streams state, rather than the value returned by `get()`.

Comment: I just compiled saying `int c = source_file.get(); if( c != EOF) { /* ... */ }` and that compiled without error so does `EOF` give me the same thing as the `.eof()` stream state?

Comment: @user3869795 No. `eof()` gives you a boolean true or false. End of file has been read or not. Traits::eof() is a value that the standard (Could be reading **char.traits.require** wrong, though) guarantees won't be in the character set.